# Google Directions API destination accuray

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, directions

I'm using Google Directions API to get directions from origin GPS Co-Ordinates to destination GPS Co-Ordinates but the problem is depending on the GPS Co-Ordinates Google picks a side of the road at the destination. Sometimes this works out fine but other times it picks the wrongs side so the directions go past the destination for up to several kilometers and then takes a U turn at a safe point on the road and comes back.

Is there a way I can requestion directions to within say 20 meters of the destination rather than the absolute closest point on the road which is sometimes on the opposite side of the road?

Comment: Where do you get your coordinates from? Maybe you need coordinates on the correct side of the road.

Comment: Destinations are stored locally in an xml file. I was thinking of that as a workaround but to do this I would have to determine which direction the vehicle is coming from and use the correct side of the road as my destination. It seems a little bit clunky, it would be nice if there was a way google would automatically do it.